# Error while installing ardupilot required packages

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

Following the steps on this page : https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/building-setup-linux.html#building-setup-linux

while running : Tools/environment_install/install-prereqs-ubuntu.sh -y

I was faced with this error :

```
Collecting dronecan
  Using cached dronecan-1.0.16.tar.gz (97 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-aKWEZT/dronecan/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-aKWEZT/dronecan/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-LAoXPD
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-aKWEZT/dronecan/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-aKWEZT/dronecan/setup.py", line 19, in <module>
        with open("README.md", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as fh:
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3; however, version 20.3.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 on dual boot with windows. Newly installed it.
codes I tried :

1. *pip install auto-py-to-exe* (was given a Syntax error : invalid syntax)
2. *python3 -m pip install pyinstaller* (Error : no module named pip )
3. I installed pip with no errors using :
   *sudo apt-get install python3-pip*
4. I ran this again with no errors:

*python3 -m pip install pyinstaller*

5. Tried running this again :
   *pip install auto-py-to-exe*
   but was given this error :
   **File "setup.py", line 63
   file=sys.stderr)
   ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

---

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python /home/raed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpkZrptu Check the logs for full command output.
**

6. Tried this :
   *pip install gevent --pre*
   which ran with no errors.
7. Tried this again :
   *pip install auto-py-to-exe*
   but I got the same error as in step 1.
8. tried this :
   *pip install pyinstaller==3.5*
   successfuly installed with no errors.
9. Finally ran this again and it worked without any errors.
   *pip install auto-py-to-exe*
10. Buut running my original line (Tools/environment_install/install-prereqs-ubuntu.sh -y) I was faced with the exact same error.
11. Tried running this as a last try :
    *pip install -U setuptools*
    which worked with no errors.
    Ran the main line again and got the same error.

I know this is a lot but im really hoping someone can help me. Just know that I am totally new to linux and im still learning to use it.
Whenever im faced with an error I just google it and try whatever code makes sense.
I know that I tried a lot of code randomly but i have been so frustrated using ubuntu for the last two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and found this update to 'install-prereqs-ubuntu.sh' and it fixed the issue for me.
https://github.com/JPJSea/ardupilot/commit/df03f3c77d6a259d77e796a41c040030b3ad3a8e

As shown in the link above, I replaced this line in `Tools/environment_install/install-prereqs-ubuntu.sh`:

```
PYTHON_PKGS="future lxml pymavlink MAVProxy pexpect flake8==3.7.9 requests==2.27.1 monotonic==1.6 geocoder empy configparser==4.0.2 click==7.1.2 decorator==4.4.2 dronecan"
```

with this:

```
PYTHON_PKGS="future lxml pymavlink MAVProxy pexpect flake8==3.7.9 requests==2.27.1 monotonic==1.6 geocoder empy configparser==4.0.2 click==7.1.2 decorator==4.4.2"
```